# Why does Visual Studio create loop directory structure when publishing an ASP.Net Core web MVC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msdeploy

When I publish an ASP.Net Core MVC website, it create a recursive directory as below image.

How can I stop it?

[image]

Comment: I've run into this same thing.  Have you found anything out on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall Visual Studio update 3 may solve this issue